# SwiftUI Inspector - how to get it correctly open en close

Tags: xcode, swiftui, macos-monterey

All,

What do I want to accomplish is - A toggle for to show or hide an inspector on the right side of the window.
I have the following code. I did add everything in one file to show it here and to check it but same result.

```
@main
struct Splitview_InspectorApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .windowStyle(HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle())
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text: String = "With Inspector"
    @State var text2: String = "Without Inspector"
    @State var showInspector = true

    @State var inspectorWidth = 180.0
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { window in
            if showInspector {
                NavigationView {
                    TextEditor(text: $text)
                        .frame(minWidth: window.size.width - inspectorWidth)
                        .toolbar {
                            DocumentToolBarItems(showInspector: $showInspector)
                        }
                    InspectorView()
                        .toolbar {
                            InspectorToolBarItems(showInspector: $showInspector)
                        }
                }
                .navigationViewStyle(.columns)
            } else {
                NavigationView {
                    TextEditor(text: $text2)
                        .frame(width: window.size.width)
                        .toolbar {
                            DocumentToolBarItems(showInspector: $showInspector)
                            InspectorToolBarItems(showInspector: $showInspector)
                        }
                }
                .navigationViewStyle(.columns)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DocumentToolBarItems: ToolbarContent {
    @Binding var showInspector: Bool
    var body: some ToolbarContent {
        ToolbarItem(content: {
            Label("square.and.arrow.up", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
        })
        ToolbarItem(content: {
            Button(action: { showInspector.toggle() }) {
                Label("square.and.arrow.down", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.down")}
        })
        ToolbarItem(content: {
            Label("square.and.arrow.up.on.square", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up.on.square")
        })
    }
}

struct InspectorToolBarItems: ToolbarContent {
    @Binding var showInspector: Bool
    var body: some ToolbarContent {
        ToolbarItem(content: {
            Label("questionmark.circle", systemImage: "questionmark.circle")

        } )
        ToolbarItem(content: { Spacer() } )
        ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
            Button(action: { showInspector.toggle() }) {
                Label("Toggle Inspector", systemImage: "sidebar.right")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct InspectorView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("=========")
            Spacer()
            Text("Inspector")
            Text("Info")
            Spacer()
            Text("=========")
        }
    }
}
```

I am shure that I do something wrong, at least I hope.

The result is that the window shows up, but not always with the Inspector area open. It shows a small border with a resize cursor, but can't always resize it. When I click the toolbar button to toggle the Inspector, it closes the Inspector, but then (when it still shows the toolbar button) and I click on that button, it, the toolbar button, disappears. Anyway, it just don't work as it should.

Questions;

Why does it hide the toolbar buttons?

Why does it show a plus sign next to the Inspector Title?

How to get rid of the Inspector Title "Splitview Inspector".

How can I fix this to get it to work correctly?

Why isn't the text changing when it switches from TextEditor (curious why this work this way - not really important but I did use it as a test)?

Is this SwiftUI code 'old'? It has to run under MacOS 12.

Any suggestions? I use XCode Version 13.4.1 (13F100) and XCode Version 14.0 beta 3 (14A5270f) on a MBP 2015 retina with MacOS 12.5.

BTW - The log of XCode

```
2022-07-22 16:07:16.946691+0200 Splitview Inspector[55077:2228878] [Layout] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000019c3980 NSTabBarNewTabButton:0x7fd756047110.width == 28   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000019c3930 H:[_backgroundView]-(0)-[NSTabBarNewTabButton:0x7fd756047110]   (active, names: _backgroundView:0x7fd756418a60 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000019c39d0 H:[NSTabBarNewTabButton:0x7fd756047110]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':NSTabBar:0x7fd756415b90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000019e1d10 H:|-(0)-[_backgroundView]   (active, names: _backgroundView:0x7fd756418a60, '|':NSTabBar:0x7fd756415b90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000019c2120 'NSView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' NSTabBar:0x7fd756415b90.width == 1   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000019e1bd0 H:|-(0)-[NSTabBarScrollView:0x7fd75803da00]   (active, names: _backgroundView:0x7fd756418a60, '|':_backgroundView:0x7fd756418a60 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000019e1b80 H:[NSTabBarScrollView:0x7fd75803da00]-(0)-|   (active, names: _backgroundView:0x7fd756418a60, '|':_backgroundView:0x7fd756418a60 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6000019e2cb0 h=-&- v=-&- NSTabBarClipView:0x7fd756416e80.minX == 0   (active, names: '|':NSTabBarScrollView:0x7fd75803da00 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x6000019e1f40 h=-&- v=-&- H:[NSTabBarClipView:0x7fd756416e80]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':NSTabBarScrollView:0x7fd75803da00 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000019e1b80 H:[NSTabBarScrollView:0x7fd75803da00]-(0)-|   (active, names: _backgroundView:0x7fd756418a60, '|':_backgroundView:0x7fd756418a60 )>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, set a symbolic breakpoint on LAYOUT_CONSTRAINTS_NOT_SATISFIABLE to catch this in the debugger.
2022-07-22 16:07:16.947752+0200 Splitview Inspector[55077:2228878] [Layout] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000019c3980 NSTabBarNewTabButton:0x7fd756047110.width == 28   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000019c3930 H:[_backgroundView]-(0)-[NSTabBarNewTabButton:0x7fd756047110]   (active, names: _backgroundView:0x7fd756418a60 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000019c39d0 H:[NSTabBarNewTabButton:0x7fd756047110]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':NSTabBar:0x7fd756415b90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000019e1d10 H:|-(0)-[_backgroundView]   (active, names: _backgroundView:0x7fd756418a60, '|':NSTabBar:0x7fd756415b90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000019c2120 'NSView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' NSTabBar:0x7fd756415b90.width == 1   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000019c3980 NSTabBarNewTabButton:0x7fd756047110.width == 28   (active)>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, set a symbolic breakpoint on LAYOUT_CONSTRAINTS_NOT_SATISFIABLE to catch this in the debugger.
2022-07-22 16:07:17.034612+0200 Splitview Inspector[55077:2228878] Metal API Validation Enabled
2022-07-22 16:07:17.103943+0200 Splitview Inspector[55077:2228940] flock failed to lock list file (/var/folders/5x/8r__4snx3yscp38rs0j7dgs00000gt/C/net.apgs.dt.Splitview-Inspector//net.agps.dt.Splitview-Inspector/com.apple.metal/31001/libraries.list): errno = 35
2022-07-22 16:07:17.105433+0200 Splitview Inspector[55077:2228940] flock failed to lock list file (/var/folders/5x/8r__4snx3yscp38rs0j7dgs00000gt/C/net.agps.dt.Splitview-Inspector//net.agps.dt.Splitview-Inspector/com.apple.metal/16777237_7668488/functions.list): errno = 35
```

==

Comment: You didn’t put it in a VStack or HStack.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it'?

Comment: The navigation view that contains the Text and the InspectorView. The 2 views are not in a VStack or HStack